# How to extract global variables declared in javascript files

Tags: javascript

Is there any tool to extract global variables declared in javascript file? Var and function.

Comment: Where you need to extract the global variable?

Comment: The keys are accessible with `Object.keys(window)` for example. If you mean only the variables declared by your user script, then you just have to compare the keys before and after your script.

Comment: Have a look at minifier codes - they are preserving only global variable names

Comment: Just add the script to your page?